# How to get a json key from a Sequence File in pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a Sequence File with a key that's json. It's not a complicated schema, it's along the lines of:

```
{
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": [
    {
      "value": "Open",
      "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know you are able to load json from a file like so:

```
a = load 'a.json' using JsonLoader('[schema]');
```

and that piggybank has a way to load a Sequence file:

```
A = LOAD 'mydir/part-r-00000' USING SequenceFileLoader AS (key:long, val:long);
```

How would  I combine the two without having to write the output from the SequenceFileLoader to disk and then (re)load using the JsonLoader?

Also, I was looking at using the pattern found in  WritableConverters in the SequenceFileLoader from Elephant Bird, but Elephant Bird requires protocol buffers and hive to be installed. I don't have much control on my cluster to install those software packages.

Am I stuck with writing a UDF?

Answer (score 0):

Given the restrictions I imposed with not using Elephant Bird, I read the file in with a SequenceFileLoader and sent that value into a udf to parse out the json (and in my case, return a map).